# Mouse sensitivity not working

Tags: mouse

I bought a new Logitech G502 Hero today and the sensitivity was way too high. I am using xubuntu on my lenovo thinkpad. I went to mouse in touchpad in my settings and cranked them all the way down for the mouse but nothing has changed. Somebody please help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, there's a button in the middle which changes hardware DPI - use it.
2. Secondly, you can set up DPI for all the levels using Piper:

```
sudo apt get install piper
```

Then run it and set up DPI for your taste:

https://itsfoss.com/piper-configure-gaming-mouse-linux/

Comment: Works only for the listed supported mice:
https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/tree/master/data/devices